# In Ruby why does it seems like strings behave like arrays but then have strange behavior?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

In Ruby, I'm not sure if a string is an array; it seems to behave as one though.  It eventually does strange things that I'm not understanding at the end of this example.

```
movie = "Ghost"
puts movie[0]  #prints out G, acting like an array

#Seems like a string is actually stored as an array?
#But what's happening in the following: 
strange = "ABC"
strange[0] = "z" 
puts strange   # prints zBC. Expected - behaves like an array.
strange [0] = "aa"
strange [1] = "bb"
puts strange  # now prints out "abbBC". NOT expected. Expected is "aabbC" 

#Also this may be a factor to my confusion? 
mov = "Foo"               
puts mov                 
puts mov[0].object_id          
puts mov[0].object_id         # Different each time you look at the same thing. Why?
```

Comment: It works like an array that can only store one character per slot. In `strange [0] = "aa"` the second a is pushed away to the location [1] and then overwritten.

Comment: Tony, it becomes a lot clearer when you recognize that [String#[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D]) and [String#[\]=](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) are just ordinary instance methods in the String class. Once you understand you can just look up their documentation. Think of `strange[i]` as `string.[](i)` and `string[i] = c` as `string.[]=(i,c)`. Ruby provides what's termed "syntactic sugar" to allow you to write those methods like that. That's true with `[]` and `[]=`for other classes as well, such as `Array` and `Hash`.

Comment: If the "aa" is overwritten, then why doesn't the same occur with "bb"? Seems like if what you're saying was the case, the output for 'strange' would be "abC" or perhaps "abBC" but not "abbBC" like it is.

Comment: Once you have executed `strange[0] = 'aa'`, `strange #=> "aaBC"`, so `'BC'` has been shifted over one position. That's why `strange[1] = 'bb'` replaces the second `'a'`. Remember, `[]=` replaces one character with its argument. They don't have to be the same size strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby a `String` is not an `Array`, and the only thing both classes have in common is that they are `Object`s:

```
String.ancestors & Array.ancestors  #=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

If you're already familiar with other languages (for example C) where strings are implemented as arrays of characters and behave like arrays for all practical purposes it may generate some confusion at first.

Consider this short snippet:

```
array = ["a", "b", "c"]
string = "abc"

array[1]   #=> "b"
string[1]  #=> "b"
```

As you can see in both cases when you call the *element reference* method (`[]`) with a value of `1` a `"b"` is returned. However **you're calling two different methods** depending on if you're calling it [on an `Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) or [on a `String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). An analog thing happens when you're calling the *element assignment* method (`[]=`) [on an `Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) and [on a `String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).

The documentation of those methods is quite lengthy and I'd recommend seeing what you can do with both. The important thing to understand is that even though the `[]` and `[]=` methods share a lot of behavior between `Array`s and `String`s **they are not the same methods** and are bound to behave differently in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

String isn't stored as an array.  It may have some array like properties, but they are quite different.  To really understand why `[]` and `[]=` operate the way they do you'll need to dig into the ruby source.  I highly recommend the `pry` gem along with `pry-doc` to get access to ruby core source.

```
[1] pry(main)> s = "string"
=> "string"
[2] pry(main)> $ s[]

From: string.c (C Method):
Owner: String
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 12

static VALUE
rb_str_aref_m(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE str)
{
    if (argc == 2) {
    if (RB_TYPE_P(argv[0], T_REGEXP)) {
        return rb_str_subpat(str, argv[0], argv[1]);
    }
    return rb_str_substr(str, NUM2LONG(argv[0]), NUM2LONG(argv[1]));
    }
    rb_check_arity(argc, 1, 2);
    return rb_str_aref(str, argv[0]);
}
```

I'll leave it to you to go down the rabbit hole of what `RB_TYPE_P`, `rb_str_subpat`, and `rb_str_substr` do.

The reason why `object_id` is different every time you call `mov[0].object_id` is because that method is returning a new string *object* every time.  Every new object has it's own `object_id`.

For a more interesting example that comes up often in blog posts about performance, consider this output and why if you're appending to a string you may well want to use `<<` instead of `+=`.

```
[4] pry(main)> s = 'str'
=> "str"
[5] pry(main)> s.object_id
=> 70221767417860
[6] pry(main)> s += 'str'
=> "strstr"
[7] pry(main)> s.object_id
=> 70221767500660
[8] pry(main)> s << 'str'
=> "strstrstr"
[9] pry(main)> s.object_id
=> 70221767500660
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings and Arrays both define `[]` and `[]=` as methods, but they do not share implementation. The string implementation of `[]` simply calls the rb_str_substr(VALUE str, long beg, long len), to create a substring from the given string. In other languages there usually is an explicit `substring` method for this purpose in the string implementation.

You can see the source code linked below.

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L8915

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L5701

Also Integers behave like Arrays in Ruby and return the boolean value, however they are not Arrays and do not share implementation . It is a fun language :)

```
irb(main):005:0> a = 4
=> 4
irb(main):008:0> a[0]
=> 0
irb(main):009:0> a[1]
=> 0
irb(main):010:0> a[2]
=> 1
irb(main):007:0> a.to_s(2)
=> "100"
```